# Java Spring SAML - Cannot Send proper request to IDP (My SP is behind Load Balancer)

Tags: java, spring, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I'm trying to make SAML work. I've configured everything according to the documentation (I hope that I did..).

When I'm testing my **localhost** server as the SP with SsoCircle as IDP it **works** perfect.
But, when I'm testing my server when it's **behind a load balancer** it **fails** to work.

I've noticed that when I use the localhost server - every request to the IDP prints to the log the following line -

> AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;127.0.0.1;my.entity.id;https://idp.ssocircle.com;asaf@mail.com

But when I send from the server that is behind a load balancer it doesn't print that line. It seems as if it doesn't reach **SamlEntryPoint.java**

- Important Note - I've configured *SAMLContextProviderLB*

Attached is my WebSecurityConfig.java (a.k.a SecurityContext)

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.wss.service.saml" /* , "org.springframework.security.saml" */} )
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        /* --- Static members --- */

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);
        private static final String ENTITY_ID = "my.entity.id";
        private static final String WSS_SAML_LOGIN_SERVLET = "/Wss/samlLogin";
        private static final int HOURS_ALLOWED_FROM_PREVIOUS_LOGIN = 2;

        /* --- Members --- */

        @Autowired
        private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

        /* --- Public methods --- */

        // Initialization of the velocity engine
        @Bean
        public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
            return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
        }

        // XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
        @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
        public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
            return new StaticBasicParserPool();
        }

        @Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
        public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
            return new ParserPoolHolder();
        }

        // Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
        @Bean
        public MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager() {
            return new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
        }

        @Bean
        public HttpClient httpClient() {
            return new HttpClient(multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
        }

        // SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
        // messages
        @Bean
        public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
            SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
            samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
            samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
            return samlAuthenticationProvider;
        }

        // Provider of default SAML Context
    //    @Bean
    //    public SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProvider() {
    //        return new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
    //    }

        // Provider of default SAML Context
        @Bean
        public SAMLContextProviderLB contextProvider() {
            SAMLContextProviderLB provider = new SAMLContextProviderLB();
            provider.setScheme("https");
            provider.setServerPort(443);
            provider.setIncludeServerPortInRequestURL(false);
            provider.setServerName("staging.loadbalancer.com");
            provider.setContextPath("/");
            return provider;
        }

        // Initialization of OpenSAML library
        @Bean
        public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
            return new SAMLBootstrap();
        }

        // Logger for SAML messages and events
        @Bean
        public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
            return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
        }

        // SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
        @Bean
        public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
            WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl profileConsumer = new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
            int secondsPromPreviousLogin = HOURS_ALLOWED_FROM_PREVIOUS_LOGIN * 3600;
            profileConsumer.setMaxAuthenticationAge(secondsPromPreviousLogin);
            return profileConsumer;
        }

        // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
        @Bean
        public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
            return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
        }

        // SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
        @Bean
        public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
            return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
        }

        // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
        @Bean
        public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
            return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
        }

        // SAML 2.0 ECP profile
        @Bean
        public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
            return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
            return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
        }

        // Central storage of cryptographic keys
        @Bean
        public KeyManager keyManager() {
            DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
            Resource storeFile = loader
                    .getResource("classpath:/saml/samlKeystore.jks");
            String storePass = "nalle123";
            Map passwords = new HashMap();
            passwords.put("apollo", "nalle123");
            String defaultKey = "apollo";
            return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
        }

        @Bean
        public ProtocolSocketFactory socketFactory() {
            return new TLSProtocolSocketFactory(keyManager(), null, "default");
        }

        @Bean
        public Protocol socketFactoryProtocol() {
            return new Protocol("https", socketFactory(), 443);
        }

        @Bean
        public MethodInvokingFactoryBean socketFactoryInitialization() {
            MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
            methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(Protocol.class);
            methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("registerProtocol");
            Object[] args = {"https", socketFactoryProtocol()};

            methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(args);
            return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean
        public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
            WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
            webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
            webSSOProfileOptions.setBinding("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST");
            return webSSOProfileOptions;
        }

        // Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
        // properties file
        @Bean
        public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
            SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
            WebSSOProfileOptions options = defaultWebSSOProfileOptions();
            samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(options);
            return samlEntryPoint;
        }

        // Setup advanced info about metadata
        @Bean
        public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
            ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
            extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(true);
            extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
            //extendedMetadata.setSigningKey("apollo");
            return extendedMetadata;
        }

        // IDP Discovery Service
        @Bean
        public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
            SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
            idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath("/templates/saml/idpSelection");
            return idpDiscovery;
        }

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
        public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
                throws MetadataProviderException {
            String idpSSOCircleMetadataURL = "https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml";
            Timer backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
            HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
                    backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), idpSSOCircleMetadataURL);
            httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
            ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
                    new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
            extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
            extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
            return extendedMetadataDelegate;
        }

        // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust
        // is here
        // Do no forget to call initialize method on providers
        @Bean
        @Qualifier("metadata")
        public CachingMetadataManager metadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
            List providers = new ArrayList();
            providers.add(ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider());
            //providers.add(salesForceExtendedMetadataProvider());
            CachingMetadataManager metadataManager = new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
            return metadataManager;
        }

        // Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
        @Bean
        public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
            MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
            metadataGenerator.setEntityId(ENTITY_ID);
            String samlBaseUrl = BackLinkUtils.applicationBaseUrl().replace("/Wss/","");
            metadataGenerator.setEntityBaseURL(samlBaseUrl);
            logger.info("SAML base URL is: " + samlBaseUrl);
            metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
            metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
            metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager());

            return metadataGenerator;
        }

        // The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix
        // and presents SP metadata there
        @Bean
        public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
            return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
        }

        // Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
        @Bean
        public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
            SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
                    new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
            logger.info("WSS - Success redirect handler - " + WSS_SAML_LOGIN_SERVLET);
            successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(WSS_SAML_LOGIN_SERVLET);
            return successRedirectHandler;
        }

        // Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
        @Bean
        public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
            SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler =
                    new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
            failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
            failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
            return failureHandler;
        }

        @Bean
        public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
            SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
            samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
            return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
        }

        // Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
        @Bean
        public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
            SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
            samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
            return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
        }

        @Bean
        public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
            return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
        }

        // Handler for successful logout
        @Bean
        public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
            SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
            successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
            return successLogoutHandler;
        }

        // Logout handler terminating local session
        @Bean
        public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
            SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
            logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
            logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
            return logoutHandler;
        }

        // Filter processing incoming logout messages
        // First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
        // global logout
        @Bean
        public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
            return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                    logoutHandler());
        }

        // Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML
        // messages
        @Bean
        public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
            return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                    new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() },
                    new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() });
        }

        // Bindings
        private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
            final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile =
                    new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
            artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
            return artifactResolutionProfile;
        }

        @Bean
        public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
            return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
        }

        @Bean
        public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
            return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
        }

        @Bean
        public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
            return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
        }

        @Bean
        public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
            return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
        }

        @Bean
        public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
            return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
        }

        @Bean
        public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
            return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
        }

        // Processor
        @Bean
        public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
            Collection bindings = new ArrayList();
            bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
            bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
            bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
            bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
            bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
            return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
        }

        /**
         * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using SAML 2.0
         *
         * @return Filter chain proxy
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @Bean
        public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
            List chains = new ArrayList();
            chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
                    samlEntryPoint()));
            chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"),
                    samlLogoutFilter()));
            chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
                    metadataDisplayFilter()));
            chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
            chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
                    samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
            chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
                    samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
            chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
                    samlIDPDiscovery()));
            return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
        }

        /**
                * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring.
                * It represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from
         * other classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
                *
                * @throws Exception
         */
        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        /**
         * Defines the web based security configuration.
         *
         * @param   http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());
            http
                    .csrf()
                    .disable();
            http
                    .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                    .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/Wss/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            http
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }

        /**
         * Sets a custom authentication provider.
         *
         * @param   auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you are behind a load balancer, all the URLs (like assertion consumer URL) in the SP metadata must point to the LB.

Depending on the 'LB' used, you either need to use the http request to built the URLs or make them configurable.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr You right, every request point to the LB. And the idp url remains the same. So, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: From a brief look at your code it seems the metadataGenerator() method is the interesting one. As there is a logger what does it print?
Most likely the BackLinkUtils.applicationBaseUrl() method is the one to look at ... where does it come from?
Also important ... which 'LB' is used?